# What does it mean when someone says "no-one got a bad word to say about you"?

Tags: meaning

Also what word would you describe someone that you depict "no-one got a bad word to say about you"

Comment: You are *blameless* (*impeccable*, *unimpeachable*, etc etc etc).

Comment: It means you have no enemy who will *find falt with* you. You are sociable.

Comment: Well, to start with I'd say "No one has a bad word to say about you," or "No one's got a bad word to say about you."

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. The way She stated it just isn't very proper

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the phrase is that when asked about something, people have only positive things to say in response.  Similar phrases include:

*"I have nothing bad to say about xyz."*

*"There are no bad words to say about xyz."*

*"I have only good things to say about xyz."*

The *"no-one got"* part of your example is, of course, grammatically incorrect in proper English and may be simply a dialect.  This sentiment is commonly expressed without such an affectation.

Such a person might be considered to be ***"[beyond reproach](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beyond+reproach)"*** or ***"[above reproach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/above+reproach)"***

Synonyms include Dan Bron's suggestions, *blameless, impeccable, unimpeachable,* and so on.